# Can a Jupiter sized object be replaced with Venus?

Tags: mass, astrophysics, orbital-motion, planets, solar-system

If there is a planet or gas giant as **big** as Jupiter but with the same mass as Venus, be swapped in Venus's place?

I mean to ask: that close to its star.

note: COMPLETELY NATURAL.

Comment: short answer: No, there is no known mechanism that could move planets around by human deliberation.

Comment: @JanDvorak sry if the question led you to think like that, no human or technology would be involved it's all natural.

Comment: [A body with the volume of Jupiter and mass of Venus would have about the same density as aerogel](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mass+of+venus+%2F+volume+of+jupiter). [The surface gravity wouldn't crush aerogel](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=surface+gravity+of+venus+*+(radius+of+venus+%2F+radius+of+jupiter)%5E2), but I'm going to doubt the chances it could come to existence via natural means.

Comment: So are you asking if a gas giant planet can form within some smaller orbital radius than what we see in Jupiter now? Or are you asking if it's possible it can migrate from where it is to closer in?

Comment: Also, please don't add rants to the question itself. It *might* be somewhat acceptable to put it as a comment, but it's very much looked down on to write it into the question itself.

Comment: @KyleKanos thanks, i was very mad and confused when i did that.

Comment: @KyleKanos To answer your question, its the first, i mean for it to be formed. but i guess ive got the answer and the answer is no.

Comment: @khokhan: Okay. An interesting follow up (probably posted separately) might be something along the lines of *How close can a gas giant form near its star before other effects would prevent its formation?* (probably with some more details, of course)

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks. that's a good idea, i will ask it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I hate to disagree with @TausifHossain , basically, "No."

You said it yourself at the end of your question -- "that close to its star". The basic problem is the stronger solar wind as you get closer to the parent star. The lighter elements from the original collapsing cloud that remain close to the central star during its formation, but not gravitationally drawn into it, are mostly just blown outwards by the solar wind after the star "ignites". So only the heavier elements remain to form the inner planets. And that's why they're all "rocky".

And just the fact that the inner planets are all rocky should've suggested to you it's not simply coincidental, but that there's an underlying reason.

Comment: Well pointed out, the density of the planet would indeed be very low so not physically possible.

Comment: @john-forkosh I see your point. but what if it had a very far orbit like Mercury or Earth? and what if there are only 2 planets in the system then there would be more heavier elements.

Comment: @khokhan You can read all about it for yourself at, e.g., https://books.google.com/books?id=JIPhCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA183 Or just google for lots of similar information.

Comment: @JohnForkosh thanks. I did google it but I couldn't get any solid and simple answers for me to understand they mostly had equations and my math is horrible ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes,as long as the mass is same it can absolutely be possible because the diameter of Jupiter is only 139,982 km which is relatively small compared to the vast distance of about 50 million km from mercury or 108 million km from the sun.

You see although Jupiter seems quite large compared to other planets, the distances between planets and between the sun are vastly larger so ofcourse a Jupiter sized planet can be in the place of Venus( It would just look bigger from earth than previous Venus ).